# UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIPinchGestureRecogizer for zoom in AND move with bounce-pull back animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have UIImageView inside UIView.
please assume the user can only zoomin (not in this code).
if the uiimage is bigger the UIView, I need the animation that pull back the uiimage, like in the facebook app.

meaning , If user move the UIImageView up..when he lift the finger the UIImageView is pullback to cover the empty space on the bottom.

I tried to play with it, but..no luck.
thanks in advance

```
-(void)pinchGestureDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

        CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];



        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, scale, scale)];

        [recognizer setScale:1.0];
    }


   }
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    }

}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that one should work if your image is bigger than its container:

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
    }
    else if(state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        UIView *imageView = recognizer.view;
        UIView *container = imageView.superview;

        CGFloat targetX = CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame);
        CGFloat targetY = CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame);


        if(targetX>0){
            targetX = 0;
        }else if(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView.frame)<CGRectGetWidth(container.bounds)){
            targetX = CGRectGetWidth(container.bounds)-CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame);
        }

        if(targetY>0){
            targetY = 0;
        }else if(CGRectGetMaxY(imageView.frame)<CGRectGetHeight(container.bounds)){
            targetY = CGRectGetHeight(container.bounds)-CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame);
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(targetX, targetY, CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame));
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I test your code. after zoom in I move the uiimageview but I can't move it too much now and I can not move to the border. it's stay only in the center area.

your code consider the uiimageview new size after zoom in ?

Comment: obviously not ;) so try multiplying `viewSize.width` and `viewSize.height` with your current scaleFactor

Comment: Not the best, but a simple solution would be to store the scale every time it changes in a variable. How do you assign the scale to the UIImageView?

Comment: I updated my question. please check.
It was my mistake. you code was good when the UIImageView is smaller then the superview.

BUT, I meant for somthing else.
the UIImageView is bigger then superview.
when the user end the move/pan gesture, there is animation the pull back the image to cover the empty space (cause the uiimageview is bigger the superview).

the facebook app (ipad) and others apps has this pull back animation.
sorry for my mistake. if you can still help, see my updated question.

thanks !